# ACF + Wordpress, вывод постов с meta_key и meta_value

Tags: php, wordpress

```
        <?php // параметры по умолчанию
            $posts = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 0,
            'category_name'    => 'slider-main-loft-page',
            'post_type'   => 'post',
            'meta_key'    => 'where-page-post',
            'meta_value'  => get_page_link(),
            'suppress_filters' => true, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
            ) );
            foreach( $posts as $post ){
            setup_postdata($post);
            ?>
            <div class="slider-long-width-cont">
                <?php the_content() ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
        wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс ?>
```

С помощью плагина AdvancedCustomFields добавил поле с выбором страницы, на которую отправится пост. Поле возвращает ссылку формата http://domain.com/link/ и оно совпадает с get_page_link().

Из документации к функции get_posts():
Можно указать meta_key и meta_value, тогда будут получены посты, у которых есть указанное метаполе и значение которого равно указанному значение.

Что я делаю не так? Пробовал указать http://domain.com/link/ в meta_value, но посты по прежнему не выводились.

UPD: Если сменить тип поля с «Ссылка на страницу» на «Текст» и добавить к посту ссылку обычным текстом, то всё работает. При этом вывод полей абсолютно идентичный с разными типами.

Answer (score 0):

Тип поля «Ссылка на страницу» в Advanced Custom Fields на фронт действительно выводит ссылку страницы, вот только в базе хранит id.

Было:

```
'meta_value'  => get_page_link(),
```

Стало:

```
'meta_value'  => get_the_ID(),
```